# Overwrite variable or check for existance

Tags: javascript, performance, variables

I am making a simple script in Javascript, calculating some stuff like minimum, maximum etc. and I was wondering which of the following would be faster, and mostly, why:

```
var x, y, z;
function test(){
if (x === undefined)
    x = Math.min(a, b);
if (y === undefined)
    y = a / b;
if (z === undefined)
    z = a - b;
    return [x, y, z];
}
test(); test(); test();
```

or

```
function test() {
    return [Math.min(a, b), a / b, a - b]
}
```

Also, should I create variables the first way (Defining them only when requested) or should I define the variables as soon as possible, e.g. at the start of my function? I am creating a RGB to HSV script, using constant RGB values. The HSV is not nececairly always requested (User desides).

Comment: `x === undefined` -> `ReferenceError: x is not defined` . it should be `typeof x === 'undefined'`

Comment: **Always** declare variables. If you do, they are created before any code is executed, performance issues are irrelevant in that regard.

Comment: It does not matter when you declare your variables, the compiler always hoists the variable declarations

Answer (score 1):

Always define your javascript variables at the top, and use them later like:

```
'use strict';

var a, b, c;

a = 1;

if (typeof b === 'undefined') {
    b = a || c;
}

// b is now 1
```

It is worth mentioning that if you don't define a variable, it becomes a global when first used (which is very bad).
Defining a variable in a condition (e.g. `if`) is also a very bad practice.

Comment: @Pablo Yeah, I always `'use strict';`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the x,y,z values if they already exist then checking for their existance and then over writing would be a better option.

```
if (x === undefined)
    x = Math.min(a, b);
if (y === undefined)
    y = a / b;
if (z === undefined)
    z = a - b;
```

Since you are working with RGB ,this is the best practice.
Defining the variable at the start is always considered helpful and it hardly has any impact on the performance.

Comment: But the problem is, I dont know care about overwrite the variable with the same value, but I was wondering which is faster, calculating them when requested, calculating them as soon as possible, or calculating and overwriting them when requested. Something like `function getRGB() {return red, green, blue}` vs `function getRGB(return r * 256, g * 256, b * 256)` vs `function getRGB() {if (red == undefined) red = r * 256; /*etc...*/ return red, green, blue}`

Comment: initialize them at the beginning and calculate & implement as and when required.

Answer (score 0):

if the variable is not defined use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) . The Condition should be like

```
if(typeof x === 'undefined'){
//do something
}
```

Comment: variable is 100% to be defined like so: `var x;` but I am asking: Should I declare at beginning of file, when function is called but only once or when function is called but every time it is called, because I am using very simple operations like addition, subtraction, Math.min, dividing etc.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY—it is irrelevant how many times, or where, a variable is declared because variable declarations are processed once, before any code is executed.

Comment: No, overwriting variables will calculate and redefine the variable twice, and I was wondering if checking for existance would thus be faster on second try and further. (But from what Ive known, if(a == b) is equal to if(!(a-b)) I edited the example code to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally depending on context whether you want to overwrite existing value or not. Irrespective of the existence of variable if you want to perform operation then below ways is best.

```
x = Math.min(a, b);
y = a / b;
z = a - b;
```

This way it faster because in first way you are just check variable is undefined or not if undefined then perform task. Its best to directly perform task.

hope this helps you.

Comment: But what if I only need them to be calculated once? They will be constant after that anyway, or a otherwise x, y and z will be undefined again